# Pyinstaller Created Executable Opens Blank Terminal and Does Nothing

Tags: python, debugging, pyinstaller, executable

I have a script/app I'm trying to make that interpolates X,Y data. The script itself runs in python just fine, but when I try to package as a single standalone executable it does not work. This is my first time building an .exe so any guidance is appreciated. Images are shown below.

The app is 600mb so I can't add, but all the relevant files are at my github link: https://github.com/MDJonesBYU/Interpolation-App

I'm using pyinstaller to package the .py file using the code below:

```
import subprocess
import time 
start = time.time()
print(start)
# Define the command to run PyInstaller with necessary options
pyinstaller_command = "pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=mx.DateTime --hidden-import=MySQLdb --hidden-import=pkg_resources --hidden-import=pyarrow.compat --name test_interpolator InterpolatorV2.py"

# Run PyInstaller and capture the output
process = subprocess.Popen(pyinstaller_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

# Display the output in real-time
while True:
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print(line.strip())

# Wait for the process to finish
process.wait()
print("PyInstaller process completed.")
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

The major warnings thrown (listed under the exe attempt file) include hidden import warnings for MySQLDB, mx.DateTime and pyarrow. There are other warnings, but these were thrown even when I called to import them. Any advice regarding how I can resolve this?

Non-working Executable:

[image]
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Working .py file:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOG5p.png